# How do I create space between elements in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout for this website using flexbox but the `justify-content` property doesn't seem to be working. Ultimately, I want it to look like this:

[image]

I have the grid laid out correctly but can't get space between elements at this point. This is what I've got right now:

[image]

How do I align my content correctly? Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/caseycling/pen/poNXRXZ

```css
.service-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img {
  margin: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.container>div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around; //Not working
}

.service {
  flex: 40%;
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='service-container'>
  <div class='img'>IMG</div>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class='service'>Service</div>
    <div class='service'>Service</div>
    <div class='service'>Service</div>
    <div class='service'>Service</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a `gap: 10px;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you attach `space-around` in wrong place. Now you have it on `container` which is only the left rectangle. This property will affect everything inside but not outside. You should add this prop to the highest wrapper which in this case is `service-container`

```css
.service-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; // working here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary flex container has `justify-content: center` applied.

You don't want to center the items, it seems. You want them separated like in your image.

So use `justify-content: space-between`.

---

But if you still want the layout centered, set a width to the container and use the `margin` property.

```css
.service-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img {
  margin: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.container>div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around; //Not working
}

.service {
  flex: 40%;
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='service-container'>
  <div class='img'>IMG</div>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class='service'>Service</div>
    <div class='service'>Service</div>
    <div class='service'>Service</div>
    <div class='service'>Service</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-right` to `.img`

```
.img {
    margin: .5rem;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px; // Increase space between image and servies
}
```